# How to stream large array from server to browser at 30+ Hz

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, stream

I have arrays of about 300 000 elements that I want to stream from server to browser at a 30+ Hz frequency. To that end I tried using socket.io-stream, but could not make it work. The closest thing I managed was to send 300 000 elements at a time, which of course was not efficient enough.

The array I am playing with is:

```
const allFrames = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  var frame = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < 512 * 256; k++) {
    var rand = Math.random();
    frame.push([rand, rand, rand]);
  }
  allFrames.push(frame);
}
```

I am trying to stream one of the frames at a time to the browser. I use a counter to iterate through the frames in a loop.

I'd be happy about any suggestions.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm looking into using websockets to stream data to clients.

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket